# Getting this strange error when testing an api

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2010

for school we need to create an Android App with data from an api.
I was following this tutorial from school and everything went well.
But then I came at the testing part and I get this error everytime.

**So here is the full error:**

```
{Java.Net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.tronalddump.io": No address associated with hostname ---> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0006e] in <89755ea61d9c4ae0a40ce90b872c9e2d>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeAbstractVoidMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00014] in <89755ea61d9c4ae0a40ce90b872c9e2d>:0 
  at Javax.Net.Ssl.HttpsURLConnectionInvoker.Connect () [0x0000a] in <2df86f44c8e946618f31cb3aed952f5b>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+<>c__DisplayClass44_0.<ConnectAsync>b__0 () [0x0007d] in <2df86f44c8e946618f31cb3aed952f5b>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2476 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler.DoProcessRequest (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, Java.Net.URL javaUrl, Java.Net.HttpURLConnection httpConnection, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken, Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler+RequestRedirectionState redirectState) [0x0012e] in <2df86f44c8e946618f31cb3aed952f5b>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x002d0] in <2df86f44c8e946618f31cb3aed952f5b>:0 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) [0x000b3] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs:531 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetStringAsyncCore (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] getTask) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs:147 
  at TronaldDump.Repositories.TronaldDumpRepository.GetRandomQuoteAsync () [0x0004e] in C:\2020-2021-DEVPROG-PROJECT-StruyveMattice\TronaldDump\TronaldDump\Repositories\TronaldDumpRepository.cs:32 
  --- End of managed Java.Net.UnknownHostException stack trace ---
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.tronalddump.io": No address associated with hostname
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:105)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1154)
    at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:175)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:141)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:83)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:174)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
    at libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.android_getaddrinfo(BlockGuardOs.java:172)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:137)
    ... 15 more
}
```

Comment: What Server IP address are you trying connect your Android to?  The address you are using is not found.  The error could mean the IP does exist but not service is running.

Comment: I'm trying to reach "https://www.tronalddump.io/". The website is fine. My teacher tried it at his Pc and it works fine.

Comment: Do you have the INTERNET permission set? It looks like a network access issue

Comment: Both the ACCES_NETWORK_STATE and INTERNET are checked

Comment: Is teacher in a private network and you are working from home where IP is not accessible.  Try a ping from cmd.exe >Ping tronalddump.io

Comment: We are both working from home because of COVID. When I try to ping I get a reply.
I also tried connecting to my phone's hotspot, still get the same error.